# Gridview blank space when zoom out

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in asp.net. When I zoom out the page a blank space seems in the gridview as in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDDP1.png). How to fix it?

The css code:

```
.module {
border: 1px solid #9BA0AF;
margin: 0;
margin-top: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 15px;
background: #ffffff;
position:static;
height: 100%;
width:100px;
background-size: contain;
 }

.moduleheader {
height: 38px;
width: 100%;
background: #F1F1F4 url(../images/secondary_bar.png) repeat-x;
background-position: left top;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

I also have css code above the gridview inside a div element.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #9BA0AF; width:30%; margin: 20px 3% 0 3%;      background-color:white;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        overflow: hidden !important; position:static; background-size: 100% 100%;">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None" RowStyle-Wrap="false">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution! I added the max-width property to the div as below:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #9BA0AF; width:30%; margin: 20px 3% 0 3%; background-color:white;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        overflow: hidden !important; position:static; background-size: 100% 100%; max-width: 500px;">
```